# Downloaded image dont show it in maven project

Tags: image, maven, dynamic

I have a maven project and i download images dinamicly in folder `\src\main\webapp\images\`, but dont show it in browser. Example:

```
|- src
    |- main
        |- java
        |- resources
        |- webapps
            |- images
                 |- image1.jpg (fixed)
                 |- image2.jpg (fixed)
                 |- image3.jpg (downloaded with my app)
```

If i show `image1.jpg` or `image2.jpg` works perfecty, but if i try show `image3.jpg` dont works:

```
<img src="images/image1.jpg" /> <!-- Works -->
<img src="images/image2.jpg" /> <!-- Works -->
<img src="images/image3.jpg" /> <!-- Not Works -->
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Without your pom it's hard to guess what's wrong.

Comment: How do you run your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... as far as I understand your are modifying your web-app resources at runtime. It works fine in eclipse because eclipse do kind of hot-deployement when your workspace is modified (i.e. when a new file is added in your webapp dir it is automatically available as a webresource for your appserver).

I don't think it's a good design. Imagine you download one image, then redeploy your webapp: the downloaded image will be lost.

Instead of putting your downloaded images in your web app resources: put them somewhere else (outside the war hierarchy, maybe in a directory managed by your web server)